# SQL: select all users for whom all orders meet a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, one with users and one with orders (I can join the tables on user_id). I'd like to identify users for whom ALL of their orders meet a set of conditions (say, status = "shipped"). For example, for the data below I'd want the query to return only user 2. What's the best way of doing this?

users:

| user_id | us_state |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CA |
| 2 | MI |
| 3 | TX |
| 4 | NY |

orders:

| order_id | status | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | "pending" | 1 |
| b | "shipped" | 1 |
| c | "shipped" | 2 |
| d | "shipped" | 2 |
| e | "pending" | 3 |
| f | "pending" | 1 |

I tried queries like the following but I don't think that's doing the right thing:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM orders
WHERE user_id = ALL (
  SELECT user_id
  FROM orders
  WHERE status = 'shipped'
);
```

Comment: Updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be to get the count of status = 'shipped' and status <> 'shipped' for each user and see if the count of status <> 'shipped' is 0. This may not be the best solution, but it works.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM (
    SELECT u.user_id, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.status = 'shipped' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_shipped,
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.status = 'pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_pending
    FROM users u
    JOIN orders o on o.user_id = u.user_id
    GROUP BY u.user_id
) foo
WHERE foo.count_pending = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The **ALL** operator:

- returns a boolean value as a result
- returns TRUE if ALL of the subquery values meet the condition
- is used with SELECT, WHERE and HAVING statements
- ALL means that the condition will be true only if the operation is true for all values in the range.

---

```
--Select    * From  (
    SELECT Distinct us.user_id
    ,       us.us_state
    ,       Count(IIF(ord.status = 'shipped',1,Null)) over (partition by us.user_id) AS shippedCount
    ,       Count(IIF(ord.status = 'pending',1,Null)) over (partition by us.user_id) AS pendingCount

    FROM users  us
    JOIN orders ord 
    on ord.user_id = us.user_id
    Where us.user_id=2 --)Tmp Where pendingCount=0
```

You can remove the comment symbols from the code (--)